# How to wait for flow to return before sending intent

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have a service which launches a flow collector.

The collector waits for `mainRepository.refreshAll()` to do some network calls and return a hashmap. The issue is that the intent is being broadcast before `refreshAll()` has time to return the hashMap.

How can I wait for the collector to receive hashMap before sending the intent?

```
/*start service*/
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    val intent = Intent()

    val job = CoroutineScope(Main).launch {
        mainRepository.refreshAll() /*do some work*/
            .onEach { hashMap ->
                intent.putExtra("hashMap", hashMap)
            }
            .launchIn(serviceScope)
    }

    sendBroadcast(intent)
    stopSelf()
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
}
```

Comment: What you’re doing in the coroutine doesn’t look right. You put every value emitted into the Intent using the same key, so only the last emitted value is used in the Intent. What did you intend to do? What does `refreshAll()` actually do? Based on its name it seems very weird that it would return a Flow instead of a single collection or a Deferred of a single collection.

Comment: `refreshAll()` does some networks and caching operations and returns a hashMap. I am using `refreshAll()` in my ViewModel hence why it returns a Flow object. I now want to call the same function in a service.

Comment: But does it return multiple hash maps? Is it doing multiple refreshes? Currently you are only using the last item of the Flow. If it only returns a single item, it should be a Deferred instead of Flow, or it can be simply a suspend function that directly returns HashMap.

Comment: It is only returning a single item. I agree that a Deferred makes more sense in this use case. I heard that Flow was good to use with viewmodel and network/caching so my return of hash map had been built with Flow wrapped around it. Now I am a bit confused as to whether I should be using Flow or basic suspend functions for my network/caching operations...

Answer (score 1):

Try to send the broadcast in `onEach` function block, it should work:

```
mainRepository.refreshAll()
        .onEach { hashMap ->
            intent.putExtra("hashMap", hashMap)
            sendBroadcast(intent)
        }
        .launchIn(serviceScope)
```

Comment: Thanks this is the result I ended up implementing. I am still intrigued as to how to wait for the collector to receive and then run code outside the block. Is there no functionality built in for this? I thought `onCompletion` would help but had no luck when I tried it.

Comment: `onCompletion` is invoked when flow  is completed. If I'm not mistaken there is no way to wait  for the collector to receive and run code outside the block.

Comment: "`onCompletion` is invoked when flow is completed" - isn't this the same as waiting for collector to receive?

Comment: This is the same if `Flow` is cold and emits only once, in this case the onEach and onCompletion will be invoked almost at the same time.